# Purpose of ANTLR lexer "tokens" section

Tags: antlr, antlr4

The [docs](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/dev/doc/lexer-rules.md) for lexer rules shows the following example for the lexer command `type(...)`

```
lexer grammar SetType;
tokens { STRING }
DOUBLE : '"' .*? '"'   -> type(STRING) ;
SINGLE : '\'' .*? '\'' -> type(STRING) ;
WS     : [ \r\t\n]+    -> skip ;
```

I can't find any documentation for `tokens { STRING }`.
What is it about? Why should I use it?

Comment: The tokens section comes in handy when (1) you are returning a token type, via `-> type(...)`, that is different from the name of the lexer rule. (2) you want to assign the value (an integer) of the token type, because you want to have a consistent token type value in your code. Most of the time you won't need it because for most grammars, the name of the lexer rule is the token type. In the example, there are different "STRING" syntax.

Comment: @kaby76 thank you! When you say "assign the value, an integer", can I assign an arbitrary number, or is it only dependant on order?

Comment: Oh, I may be wrong on assigning a value for the token type in the tokens sections. https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/5b3f1b73e86588721f65b2601b8ccfb3923aec17/antlr/antlr4/ANTLRv4Parser.g4#L120 Looks like the assign was not the token type, but the literal value in Antlr3. https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/5b3f1b73e86588721f65b2601b8ccfb3923aec17/antlr/antlr3/ANTLRv3Parser.g4#L42 . Sorry.

Comment: @kaby76 no problem. I've seen that placing the token names in the tokens section will give them a specific order.

Comment: However, the integer values won't be aligned anymore with what the parser stores, so pretty much nothing will work. Seems like the rule should be "include a token in the tokens section only if NOT already defined".

Comment: It does set the token type integer order. Make sure you split your grammar, and run the tool over the lexer grammar first, then the parser grammar. The values are stored in the .tokens file. If you see the parser and lexer .tokens files are different you have a problem building your parser.

Comment: @kaby76 Thanks for the heads up! I'm using the Gradle ANTLR plugin, will check what's going wrong there.

Comment: @kaby76 the .tokens files were not cleaned up on re-generation, resulting in stale items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tokens` section defines so-called virtual tokens. They are virtual in the sense that there's no lexer rule which represents that token. You may remember that token names are derived from the lexer rule that define them.

Sometimes, however, you need more differentiation. For example you have a lexer rule for numbers, but you wan to distinguish between SHORT, LONG, WORD etc. You can then define virtual tokens for those special values:

```
tokens { SHORT, LONG, WORD }
```

and ANLTR will define those as token types. Then you can write a number rule that returns one of those virtual types. Like:

```
NUMBER: DIGITS { this._type = this.determineNumericType(this.text); };
```

Note: the code given above is used in a JS/TS environment. You have to adjust it to your target language.

By default the lexer would assign the token value `NUMBER` to the captured digits, but with the action you can assign any token value you want.

Comment: Thanks Mike! Question tho, is this really possible? `NUMBER: [0-9]+ -> {...}`
An action where normally commands would be?

Comment: Sorry, no, I started with the `-> type()` lexer command and then changed it to an action block (and forgot to remove the arrow).  The lexer action is useful for fixed token type replacements (usually to define keyword aliases like `DEC_SYMBOL:  'DEC'-> type(DECIMAL_SYMBOL); // Synonym`.

Comment: @LppEdd No, [lexer commands cannot be actions](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/3564c6347810cbcc55248ed7ee70401b26354c4d/antlr/antlr4/ANTLRv4Parser.g4#L269-L286). But you can use [a tail action](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/3564c6347810cbcc55248ed7ee70401b26354c4d/gdscript/GDScriptLexer.g4#L61), lexer command, or [both](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/3564c6347810cbcc55248ed7ee70401b26354c4d/bencoding/BencodingLexer.g4#L14). A lexer command can be written using method calls in an action. Many examples in grammars-v4.

Comment: @kaby76 thank you! Is the $text variable above related to the PHP language, or is it a placeholder that instructs ANTLR to pass in the scanned token text?

Comment: @LppEdd `$text` is an Antlr attribute. https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/actions.md#parser-rule-attributes

Comment: @MikeLischke apparently you can't use $text in lexers. ANTLR returns "attribute references not allowed in lexer actions: $text". Does it need some kind of special config?

Comment: I see. However you can access the current token in your action code. I updated the answer.